# What's the kurtosis of exponential distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

**Original question** (with confused terms):

Wikipedia and Wolfram Math World claim that the kurtosis of exponential distribution is equal to $6$. Whenever I calculate the kurtosis in math software (or manually) I get $9$, so I am slightly confused.

I calculate 4th central moment as:

$$
D^4X = \int_0^\infty (x-\lambda^{-1})^4 \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \, dx\,.
$$

And kurtosis as:

$$
K = \frac{D^4X}{(D^2X)^2}
$$

Is the **approach and result** correct (kurtosis equal to $9$)? I trust that the calculation of this very specific integral I shown is correct.

**Comment:**

I didn't know '**kurtosis**' and '**excess kurtosis**' are different terms. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: If a statement on MathWorld is confusing to you just ignore it. MathWorld isn't editable the way Wikipedia is so it's a lot easier for bizarre mistakes to sneak in; I've seen all sorts of weird nonstandard definitions and things like that on it.

Comment: Thank you for the support. I probably got confused by wikipedia redirecting "excess kurtosis" to "kurtosis" and then explaining the difference within.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Often "kurtosis" is taken to mean "excess kurtosis", i.e. the amount by which the kurtosis exceeds that of the normal distribution, thus the kurtosis minus $3.$

Subtraction of $3$ makes sense in some contexts even without thinking about the normal distribution. Let $\mu=\operatorname{E}(X)$ and note that the two functionals
$$
\operatorname{A}(X) = \operatorname{E}\big((X-\mu)^4\big) \quad \text{and} \quad \operatorname{B}(X) = \Big(\operatorname{E}\big((X-\mu)^2\big) \Big)^2
$$
are $(1)$ homogenous of degree $4$ (i.e. multiplying $X$ by a scalar $c$ multiplies the value of the functional by $c^4,$ and $(2)$ translation-invariant. But they are not "cumulative", i.e. for independent random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ we do not have $\operatorname{A}(X_1+\cdots+X_n) = \operatorname{A}(X_1)+\cdots+\operatorname{A}(X_n)$ nor $\operatorname{B}(X_1+\cdots+X_n) = \operatorname{B}(X_1)+\cdots+\operatorname{B}(X_n).$ But $\kappa = {\operatorname{A}}-{3\operatorname{B}}$ is homogenous of degree $4$ and translation invariant and cumulative. And for any coefficient besides $-3$ that doesn't work. This quantity $\kappa(X)$ is the fourth cumulant of the distribution of $X.$ The excess kurtosis is
$$
\frac{\kappa(X)}{\sigma^4}.
$$

Answer (score 8):

A more careful reading of the [MathWorld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Kurtosis.html) states that the **kurtosis excess** of an exponential distribution is $6$.  This is not the same as kurtosis, since the former is defined as $$\gamma_2 = \frac{\mu_4}{\mu_2^2} - 3,$$ (see Equation 3), as opposed to the simple kurtosis $$\beta_2 = \frac{\mu_4}{\mu_2^2},$$ which is Equation (1).  The reason for these two definitions is also explained in the article, since $\beta_2$ for a normal distribution is $3$, hence the definition of kurtosis excess representing in some sense the amount of kurtosis *in excess* of a normal distribution.

Therefore, there is no error.  MathWorld is correct.

Comment: And [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) says "**Ex. kurtosis** $6$" in its infobox

Answer (score 3):

I get for $\lambda=1$
$$\int_0^\infty(x-1)^4\exp(-x)\,dx=9.$$
In general I get
$$\int_0^\infty(x-1)^n\exp(-x)\,dx=D_n,$$
the $n$-th derangement number.

Wikipedia is correctable.

Comment: "Wikipedia is correctable" although in this case it needs no correction. OP misunderstood what it said.

Comment: Wikipedia explicitly says $6$ is the excess kurtosis, not that it is the raw kurtosis.